# How can I recreate this table?

Tags: tables, multirow, tabulary

I want to use the same type of setup used in this figure, however I can't seem to find out how to add the multirow in a way which doesn't give me an error when compiling.

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Welcome :) // How to do tables, please have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables . Once you succeeded, have a look here for alternatives, e.g. easytable etc.: https://www.ctan.org/topic/table . We are looking forward for your first attempts in code.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would use multirow for that table at all. I would just do something like load the array package, and use a column specifier like m{4cm} that allows for line breaks for the rows where some lines are broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not really much to do: count the number of rows to span.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\DeclareSIUnit{\voltac}{VAC}
\DeclareSIUnit{\kilogrammetre}{kgm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\multirow{9}{*}{PMSG} &
  Rated Power & \qty{2}{\mega\watt} \\
& Rated rotate speed & \qty{650}{rpm} \\
& Rated Voltage & \qty{690}{\voltac} \\
& Rated current & \qty{1673.5}{\ampere} \\
& Number of pole pairs & 4 \\
& Resistance ($R_s$) & \qty{0.0024}{\ohm} \\
& Inductances ($L_d=L_q$) & \qty{0.3552}{\milli\henry} (line-phase) \\
& Magnetic flux ($\Psi_m$) & \qty{0.666}{\weber} \\
& Inertia (J) & \qty{2}{\kilogrammetre^2} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{Grid side Filter} &
  Inductance & \qty{1.6}{\milli\henry} \\
& Resistance & \qty{0.01}{\ohm} \\
& Rated charge/discharge currents & \qty{1500}{\ampere} \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Complete.

[image]

On the other hand, such a table is very hard to read. Here's a different proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareSIUnit{\voltac}{VAC}
\DeclareSIUnit{\voltrms}{Vrms}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\newcommand{\partheader}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\itshape #1}}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\quad}lll@{}}
\toprule
\partheader{PMSG} \\
  Rated Power & \qty{2}{\mega\watt} \\
  Rated rotate speed & \qty{650}{rpm} \\
  Rated Voltage & \qty{690}{\voltac} \\
  Rated current & \qty{1673.5}{\ampere} \\
  Number of pole pairs & 4 \\
  Resistance & \qty{0.0024}{\ohm} & $R_s$ \\
  Inductances & \qty{0.3552}{\milli\henry} & $L_d=L_q$, line-phase \\
  Magnetic flux & \qty{0.666}{\weber} & $\Psi_m$ \\
  Inertia & \qty{2}{\kilogram\square\metre} & J \\ 
\midrule
\partheader{Grid side Filter} \\
  Inductance & \qty{1.6}{\milli\henry} \\
  Resistance & \qty{0.01}{\ohm} \\
  Rated currents & \qty{1500}{\ampere} & charge/discharge \\
\midrule
\partheader{Grid} \\
  Voltage & \qty{690}{\voltrms} \\
  Frequency & \qty{50}{\hertz} \\
\midrule
\partheader{Generator Side Filter} \\
  Inductance & \qty{1}{\milli\henry} \\
  Resistance & \qty{0.01}{\ohm} \\
\midrule
\partheader{DC-link} \\
  Total power & \qty{265}{\kilo\watt} \\
  DC-link voltage & \qty{1200}{\volt} & $V_{\mathrm{dc}}$ \\
  DC-link current & \qty{1000}{\ampere} & $I_{\mathrm{dc\_max}}$ \\
\midrule
\partheader{Supercapacitor} \\
  Capacitance & \qty{15.8}{\farad} & \qty{83}{\farad}, 21 in series, 4 parallel loop \\
  Resistance & \qty{52.5}{\milli\ohm} & $R_{\mathrm{sc}}$ \\
  Voltage Initial & \qty{650}{\volt} & $V_{\mathrm{initial}}$, $C_{\mathrm{sc\_nominal}}$ \qty{48}{\volt} each \\
\midrule
\partheader{Reference Values} \\
  Active Power & \qty{265}{\kilo\watt} \\
  Reactive Power & 0 \\
\midrule
\partheader{Other} \\
  Sample Time Rec. & \qty{1e-4}{\second} \\
  Sample Time Inv. & \qty{1e-4}{\second} \\
  Sample Time bidirectional & \qty{7e-5}{\second} \\
  Simulator Run Time & \qty{20}{\second} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]